# Permaneantly deleted files remain searchable

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

So I had a fault on my GPT (4TB HDD) disk (not used as a boot disk on my Windows 10 64-bit setup) a few days back. The disk was not being recognized (or something similar - I can't really recall) under "Disk Management" and wanted me to reformat the drive. Unsure how to really handle the issue, I used AOEMI Partition Assistant to rebuild the MBR. A reboot then appeared to resolve the problem.

Now when I delete files from the disk, although the removed file size is updated to the disk space, the file with all its properties still appear as part of search results as if it still exists. The file I removed was a video file and trying to play it gives an expected "file does not exist" message.

Also, not sure if this is network related or not, but when I try to transfer a large file from another computer to the drive, theres kind of a stuttering - occasionally the file appears to be transferring at an appropriate speed but then go to 0 kb/s transfer for a few seconds, then back to the regular speed, and this would repeat until the file is fully transferred. There didn't seem to be a problem when transferring a file from a different drive on the same computer or transferring a file from the network to a different drive on that computer.

How can I get the disc to respond "normally" again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your drive failed, the old search results are just cached and not reliable.

You need to put the drive in a drive caddy, mount in another machine and try to retrieve the files by normal (File Explorer or DOS commands.

If, with testing, you believe the drive to be good in all ways, try rebuilding the search index.

Comment: File transfers appear to be working as normal - it just appears as if the records for new updates are not updating. Is it possible to just update the cache?

Comment: No I do not think you can update the search cache results. If the drive is truly good, try rebuilding the search index.

Comment: Seems to have done the trick! Though the issue with transferring files via the network appears to be still happening which is rather worrying. My largest (and probably most used/under stressed) HD and only around 18 months old :'(

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get the disc to respond "normally" again?

Check the health of your drive with tools like smartmontools or CrystalDiskInfo to exclude the possibility of a degrading drive.

Defragmentation should not be the issue with regards to your "downtime" indication.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! No idea why I always forget HD's have SMART tech built into them - guess I must have blocked it from memory as result of past experiences with them being quite traumatic :D. CrystalDiskInfo reported a "good" drive, though I'm still a little on the weary side due to the initial fault and the currently weird transfer speeds on the drive.

Comment: Do not rely on a summary judgment of CrystalDiskInfo. Check out various drives you have go into the single indicators and look for exceptional values in your hd collection.